Issues with Implementing International Telephone Input with Country Flag Dropdown in Angular 16
I'm attempting to implement international telephone input functionality with a country flag dropdown in Angular 16. Initially, I tried using the "ngx-mat-intl-tel-input-v16" library, but encountered several issues including improper styles and malfunctioning search functionality.
After some research, I switched to the "ngx-intl-tel-input" library, but I'm facing difficulties getting it to work properly in my Angular 16 project. Despite following the documentation and examples provided, I haven't been successful in resolving the issues.
Here are the details of my project's package.json file:
{
  "name": "tour-expert",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.10",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.10",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.10",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.10",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.10",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "awesome-phonenumber": "^3.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.34",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.3",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.59",
    "luxon": "^3.4.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-mat-intl-tel-input-v16": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular-material-extensions/select-country": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^13.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}

I've also referenced the documentation provided by the library here:https://github.com/ksr-nivas/ngxs-intl-tel-input

The package ngx-intl-tel-input doesn't have angular 16 support (only supports untill 13.x.x).
Try using the following package which supports for A16
https://github.com/maxcl10/ngx-intl-tel-input#readme
or find some other more maintainable package with the support of A16.
this link will help you for starting list
https://www.npmjs.com/search?ranking=maintenance&q=keywords%3Aintl-tel-input
PS: Since Angular 16 mandates Ivy engine compatibility, you must check whether the packages mention the A16 support.
Hope this helps ;)

https://github.com/maxcl10/ngx-intl-tel-input#readme - In this link while installing  library i got a issue which is version conflict - npm install ngx-intl-tel-input --save - This library not available for angular 16 .

sad to hear that, i haven't tried installing it , well  this link  seems like a good choice in npm, try installing using npm i ngx-mat-input-tel@16.2.1 which seem like a stable version for A16
